# Segurança com AccountManager

Tags: android

Estou utilizando o seguinte método para recolher o email do usuário para servir de autenticação(somente o email) no meu app:

```
AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{"com.google"}, false, null, null, null, null);
```

Minha dúvida é se isso é facilmente burlável e se tem como diminuir esse risco.